# Why do TVs have different input lags with computers than they do with other devices?

Tags: hdmi, external-display, lag, input

So I have two different modern TVs, different gaming laptops (relatively new, Win10, 16GB RAM), and a few gaming consoles.  Everything is rigged with HDMI.  It's a pretty standard setup.

On both of my TVs, my computers have input lag (one TV with major lag, the other is minor), while my consoles have none on either TV.

Why?

Specifically, I'm asking not about why I'm having bad input lag on my specific devices or how to fix it, but the general concern of why computers seem to generate extra input lag *at all*.

Does it have more to do with the computers, or the TVs?

Comment: Too many potential answers - perhaps you can at least give lag measurements on the Human Benchmark (reaction time might help figure out lag time beyond the typical 350ms) listed: https://www.techhive.com/article/183928/how-to-find-and-fix-input-lag-in-your-hdtv-or-monitor.html

Comment: Since you mentioned your gaming computers are laptops, I'm going to guess that it's because the laptops are handling both the internal display and the HDMI output, whereas your consoles are controlling the HDMI output only.  You could test this theory by setting the HDMI out on your laptops as the primary monitor and disabling the internal screen (show on external primary only).  See if that setup affects your input lag.

Comment: @Blaelph I remember trying that a while back and that it didn't have much success, but I will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a lot of factors, too many to list, you need to be more specific about your situation.

But if you happen to have a Samsung TV, those pay undue attention to what kind of device is plugged into them, and don't totally respect their "game mode" setting when they detect a computer plugged in. The lag is about halfway between normal (no game mode) and game mode, at least on the most recent Samsung TV I tested, a 2019 4k Tv.

On other TVs, such as those made by TCL or Sony the type of device plugged in makes no difference and the lag will be identical, at least in my testing.